# Not able to use all the memory channels using testpmd

Tags: memory-management, hardware, dpdk

I am using testpmd (DPDK 17.11.1). I created two ports P0 and P1 and I sent traffic from P0 to P1. And I found that it is using only two memory channels. Following is the command to start testpmd :

```
./testpmd -n4 -l2,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33 -- --rxd=4096 --txd=4096 --numa --rxq=8 --txq=8 --nb-cores=16 --numa --forward-mode=mac -i
```

Here is the result of pcm tool which says only 2 out of 4 memory channels are being using :

```
|---------------------------------------||---------------------------------------|
|---------------------------------------||---------------------------------------|
|--             Socket  0             --||--             Socket  1             --|
|---------------------------------------||---------------------------------------|
|--     Memory Channel Monitoring     --||--     Memory Channel Monitoring     --|
|---------------------------------------||---------------------------------------|
|-- Mem Ch  0: Reads (MB/s):     0.06 --||-- Mem Ch  0: Reads (MB/s):     0.01 --|
|--            Writes(MB/s):     0.13 --||--            Writes(MB/s):     0.01 --|
|-- Mem Ch  1: Reads (MB/s):   141.17 --||-- Mem Ch  1: Reads (MB/s):  1642.35 --|
|--            Writes(MB/s):   262.84 --||--            Writes(MB/s): 11842.28 --|
|-- Mem Ch  2: Reads (MB/s):   140.44 --||-- Mem Ch  2: Reads (MB/s):  1639.97 --|
|--            Writes(MB/s):   261.67 --||--            Writes(MB/s): 11850.11 --|
|-- Mem Ch  3: Reads (MB/s):     0.46 --||-- Mem Ch  3: Reads (MB/s):     0.40 --|
|--            Writes(MB/s):     0.55 --||--            Writes(MB/s):     0.40 --|
|-- NODE 0 Mem Read (MB/s) :   282.13 --||-- NODE 1 Mem Read (MB/s) :  3282.72 --|
|-- NODE 0 Mem Write(MB/s) :   525.19 --||-- NODE 1 Mem Write(MB/s) : 23692.79 --|
|-- NODE 0 P. Write (T/s):      15496 --||-- NODE 1 P. Write (T/s):      15947 --|
|-- NODE 0 Memory (MB/s):      807.33 --||-- NODE 1 Memory (MB/s):    26975.52 --|
|---------------------------------------||---------------------------------------|
|---------------------------------------||---------------------------------------|
|--                 System Read Throughput(MB/s):       3564.86                --|
|--                System Write Throughput(MB/s):      24217.99                --|
|--               System Memory Throughput(MB/s):      27782.84                --|
|---------------------------------------||---------------------------------------|
```

How can I use all the four memory channels ?

Answer (score 0):

The number of memory channels we specify with `-n` does not do much: it just aligned each memory pool element to a different memory channel as described in [DPDK Programmer's Guide](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/prog_guide/mempool_lib.html#memory-alignment-constraints)

Even if we put an invalid number there, we still should be able to use all of the channels, maybe not that optimal. There are might be some corner cases, but those are quite rare and could be easily "fixed" not only with `-n` option but also adjusting testpmd mbuf size (i.e. memory pool element) with `--mbuf-size=N` option as described in [Testpmd User Guide](https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/testpmd_app_ug/run_app.html)

So, my guess is that the command line option does not matter that much and the real issue is that the system you use does not have four DIMM per NUMA node, i.e. there are no 8 separate DIMMs. You can try to check it with `sudo dmidecode | grep DIMM` or just physically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked into "sudo dmidecode | grep DIMM" but it looks like system has 8 DIMMs that is 4 per socket.

# dmidecode  | grep  -n DIMM
521:    Form Factor: DIMM
545:    Form Factor: DIMM
569:    Form Factor: DIMM
593:    Form Factor: DIMM
809:    Form Factor: DIMM
833:    Form Factor: DIMM
857:    Form Factor: DIMM
881:    Form Factor: DIMM

Comment: Have you tried to change mbuf size or numbers of channels, what pcm shows then?

Comment: So, i tried changing  mbufs size (4096 and 8192) and it is still the same.

Comment: One more guess: check the Memory Channel/Rank Interleaving settings in BIOS to make sure they set to auto.

Comment: I found the issue, the system originally supported 6 memory channel. We I added 4 dimms it was only using 2 of them but when I added two more, all the memory channels started working.